# How do I get secure cookies in Google developer tools?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, cookies

I have the following code...

```
String get( HttpServletResponse res ){
    Cookie c = new Cookie("sessionId", "testSession");
    c.setSecure(true);
    res.addCookie(c);
    return "index";
}
```

When I run I see...

[image]

But then in the browser I see...

[image]

Is this the way it is supposed to work or is there a way I can see the secure cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Must have been expected, good ole' Postman...

[image]